# Program Not Remembering changes

Tags: python, save

Hello I have combed threw possible solutions and I can't figure this out, I got my program working for the most part but the problem is when I close the program it doesn't remember the changes made by the user. The program stored input into variables. It works like a dictionary (I wrote the code before I knew about the dictionary function) when I open the program I can enter the input but the problem is when I close the program it forgets all the changes and goes back to how it was when first compiled. Any ideas how I can allow the data to ramain available when I close the program and reopen it?

Comment: Use [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) as your dictionary.

Comment: This will be impossible to answer without more context. What is the program, what environment, what language, what IDE, what does the program do, what variables, etc.

Comment: is it your problem like that? you have dictionary or list - and adding it some elements in your first execution, then break out it. when you return back the dictionary/list doesn't contain old values? if it's like that, write your elements/variables  to a file, or database table.

dictionaries/lists can not behave that way.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html). It is awesome Python library, which allows you to read/write dict-like data from file. For example:

```
import shelve
dict_with_data = dict(key1='value1', key2='value2')
storage = shelve.open('shelve_file')
storage.update(dict_with_data)
storage.close()
```

It is very simple example which opens shelve storage and updates it with your data. Actually you can do whatever you do with regular dictionary object, because

> A “shelf” is a persistent, dictionary-like object.

Another library that you could use is [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). It allows you serialize every kind of Python objects, but since you have dictionary structure shelve should be better for your needs.

Please fill free to ask questions/post your code, I will be glad to update my answer appropriate to you needs.

Comment: Should that be `s = shelve.open('shelve_file')`?

Comment: Yep. Thank you for notice, typo fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement two things here.

1) Your program need to take an optional input file and the best way to do it is probably to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). If you pass the input file, then you extract the data from the file and you initialize your dictionary_like object with that data.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input', help='input file name')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.input:
    ... # open the file, load the data, initialize a dict with the data
```

2) Just before quitting, you must save your data (key:value pairs) in the input file. If you want to save a dictionary like structure, a txt file with a key:value pairs for each line of the file should be good enough.

```
with open(input, 'w') as f:
    for key,value in dictionary.items():
        f.write(str(key)+':'+str(value)+'\n') #you can use '\t' or whatever instead the ':'
```

And that's it.
If you need more help on how to implement this let me know ;)

Comment: I'm a bit confused how do I make those grey squares to add my code in I see u all putting code in grey squares.

Comment: just add 4 spaces before each line of text that you want to include into the grey field

Comment: please help me to figure out where to put the pickle or shelve i have tried and failed

Comment: @trédarkgrey I have not understood what is your problem. You can contact me by email alec_djinn-at-yahoo-dot-com and I will be more that happy to help you out. But please describe precisely what is the input, what you wanna do with that and what is the expected output of your script.